# VS Code can't locate python executable and run programs through run button

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been stuck trying to install Python on VS Code for the past few hours. I've searched and found multiple answers but I still get the same error whenever I try to run a program through the run button.

```
C:/Users/tomiw/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/tomiw/Desktop/Java/test.py

-bash: C:/Users/tomiw/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe: No such file or directory
```

When I check my files I can see the executable there, but for some reason VS Code does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue for JS, the thing that fixed it for me was editing the systems properties, under the Environments variables. 
After that I rebooted my computer and it worked.
If that dosent work try manually installing Python from their site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)?

Please try uninstalling and reinstalling [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and [python extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). Follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

*Other possible workarounds:*

**Set defaultInterpreterPath:**

Add the following configuration to your `settings.json` file:

```json
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "your_python_interpreter_path",
```

**Custom interpreter path:**

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette.
2. search for **Python:Select Interpreter**.
3. select the first item **Enter interpreter path**.
4. Then paste the full path to your `python.exe` ( or go to explorer by selecting **Find** and select your `python.exe` ).